# Firefox pref is destroying JSON

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon

I have the following JSON: http://pastebin.com/Sh20StJY

<sup>SO removed the chars on my post, so look at the link for the real JSON</sup>

which was generated using `JSON.stringify` and saved on Firefox prefs (`pref.setCharPref(prefName, value);`)

The problem is that when I save the value, Firefox does something that corrupts the JSON. If I try a `JSON.parse` retrieving the value from the config I get an error:

```
Error: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal
```

[If I try to validate the above JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) (which was retrieved from the settings) I get an error at `line 20`, the tokens value contains two invalid characters.

If I try a `JSON.parse` immediately after `JSON.stringify` the error doesn't occur.

Do I have to set something to save in a different encoding? How can I fix it?

Comment: What does the saved config actually look like? The JSON in your question is valid.

Comment: @Collin I guess SO removed the chars... `Tokens` has two invisible chars: http://pastebin.com/Sh20StJY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref()` only works for ASCII data, your JSON data contains some non-ASCII characters however. You can store Unicode data in preferences, it is merely a little bit more complicated:

```
var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
str.data = value;
pref.setComplexValue(prefName, Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString, str);
```

And to read that preference:

```
var str = pref.getComplexValue(prefName, Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
var value = str.data;
```

For reference: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences)

Comment: This is super awesome! Saved my day. I have the exact issue that my UTF-8 encoded string was converted from \uxxxx to a wrong char, and `JSON.parse` simply fails when reading the stringified string. ;) +1!

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON appears to contain non-ASCII characters such as `½`.  Can you check what encoding everything is being handled in?

[`nsIPrefBranch.setCharPref()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefBranch#setCharPref%28%29) assumes that its input is UTF-8 encoded, and the return value of [`nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPrefBranch#getCharPref%28%29) is always an UTF-8 string.  If your input is a bytestring or a character in some other encoding, you will either need to switch to UTF-8, or encode and decode it yourself when interacting with preferences.

Comment: Very close but no cigar :) See my answer.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Huh, I guess I interpreted the documentation wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did this in one place to fix this issue:

```
(function overrideJsonParse() {
    if (!window.JSON || !window.JSON.parse) { 
        window.setTimeout(overrideJsonParse, 1); 
        return;  //this code has executed before JSON2.js, try again in a moment
    }
    var oldParse = window.JSON.parse;
    window.JSON.parse = function (s) {
        var b = "", i, l = s.length, c;
        for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            c = s[i];
            if (c.charCodeAt(0) >= 32) { b += c; }
        }
        return oldParse(b);
    };
}());
```

This works in IE8 (using json2 or whatever), IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct. Try use single quotes '..': '...' instead of double quotes "..":"..." .

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't find the solution, but I found a workaround:

```
var b = "";
[].forEach.call("{ JSON STRING }", function(c, i) {
    if (c.charCodeAt(0) >= 32)
        b += c;
});
```

Now `b` is the new JSON, and might work...